# Getting response from server after reconnect the internet volley

Tags: android, android-volley, network-connection

While i am hitting URL to get response from server using volley ,during the fetching  the net was disconnected .

my question is how to fetch data from server after reconnect the internet connection ,without hitting url once again

```
 private void PostRequest(String Url) {

mRequest = new ServiceRequest(HomeActivity.this);
mRequest.makeServiceRequest(Url, Request.Method.GET, null, new ServiceRequest.ServiceListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleteListener(String response) {

        Log.d("reponse", response);

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

    }


    @Override
    public void onErrorListener() {
        indicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});



 public void makeServiceRequest(final String url, int method, final 
 HashMap<String, String> param,ServiceListener listener) {

this.mServiceListener=listener;

stringRequest = new StringRequest(method, url, new Response.Listener<String> 
 () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            mServiceListener.onCompleteListener(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        try {
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof 
  NoConnectionError) {
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

         mServiceListener.onErrorListener();
    }
     }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return param;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        return headers;
    }
};

     //to avoid repeat request Multiple Time
DefaultRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, 
 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
 }
 }
```

please give suggetion,before hitting url i was checked internet connection

Comment: You must make request again, there are no other way. Maybe you ask how to do it automatically with out user's interaction?

Comment: you can use retry policy within volley library.

Comment: I don't know about volley but there is cache mechanism in `Retrofit`. You can search type of thing for volly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing, create the collection of your failed requests. Register the broadcast receiver of CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and WIFI_STATE_CHANGED to get notified when the internet connection is available. Once your device connects to the internet, you will get notified in registered broadcast receiver and then send retry all the request which are there in your collection. Once request is successful remove the request from the collection.

Comment: if the question was useful appreciate with up-vote@Savesh Athawale

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a Network Change Broadcast receiver.

Create a new class **NetWorkChangeReceiver**

```
public class NetWorkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @NonNull
    private final NetworkConnectionRestoredListener mListener;

    public NetWorkChangeReceiver(@NonNull NetworkConnectionRestoredListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (NetworkUtil.isDeviceConnectedToInternet(context)) {
            mListener.onNetworkRestored();
        }
    }

    public interface NetworkConnectionRestoredListener {
        void onNetworkRestored();
    }
}
```

Create a **NetworkUtil** class

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class NetworkUtil {

    private NetworkUtil() {
        // no instances
    }

    public static boolean isDeviceConnectedToInternet(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            for (Network network : connManager.getAllNetworks()) {
                if (network != null) {
                    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(network);

                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_WIFI);
            if (mWifi != null && mWifi.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo m3G = connManager.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (m3G != null && m3G.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                NetworkInfo mEthernet = connManager.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_ETHERNET);
                return mEthernet != null && mEthernet.isConnected();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity, implement **NetWorkChangeReceiver.NetworkConnectionRestoredListener**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetWorkChangeReceiver.NetworkConnectionRestoredListener {

NetWorkChangeReceiver mNetworkChangeReceiver;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

//Use this to register the receiver while making the server call.
context.registerReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver = new NetWorkChangeReceiver(this), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
    public void onNetworkRestored() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mNetworkChangeReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver);
                mNetworkChangeReceiver = null;
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mNetworkChangeReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver);
                mNetworkChangeReceiver = null;
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```